# Django - Cannot run "py manage.py runserver"

Tags: python, django

I have tried python manage.py runserver, same result. It says the following in the terminal:

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases
```

When I run py --version, it works fine.
I want to know why it says python was not found, when it works just fine. I haven't found anything online.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for `py --version` and on the other hand executing the command `python manage.py runserver`.

> Try : `py manage.py runserver`

And check if you have two versions of python installed on your machine.

Comment: I might be wrong here with my answer, but when I run the two different commands to check the version installed, I get two different versions.

Comment: Ok I reinstalled it and put it in PATH. Thanks so much for helping Heck. 

Answer (score 0):

If python is properly installed (available to be accessed from terminal) you should be able to simply type "python" and enter a python shell. To verify, try:

> 2 + 2

This should output 4. If typing python does not take you to the python shell, I'm guessing you need to add python as a PATH variable.

Comment: I can't. It sends me to the Microsoft store. However, I am able to enter the Python interpreter by typing py. Thanks for helping btw.

Comment: Uninstall Python, redownload from Anaconda distributer. Make sure to Add Python to PATH when configuring settings in the installation setup. Please accept my answer if your problem was solved. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, it was fixed a while ago. But your answer is correct, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using older versions of Django, say Django 3.1 and below then

`python manage.py runserver` should work ok.

I advise you to stick to `python` and not `py`.

But in the newer versions of Django, say Django 3.2 and above then
it is much simpler to run your server

simply use:
`manage.py runserver` or `python manage.py runserver`

For further reference here is the Django documentation link for **Django 3.2**
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

Before execution of runserver command you need to execute **activate** command